# A question about strftime

Tags: c++, c, datetime, time

The question is simple "Say we have an integer **1 <= n <= 12**,How to use `strftime` to display **January** for '**1**',**February** for '**2**',**March** for '**3**' and so on ... ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t monthName( char* buf, size_t size, int month)
{
    struct  tm t = {0};

    t.tm_mon = month - 1;   // turn month 1..12 to 0..11 as `struct tm` wants

    return strftime( buf, size, "%B", &t);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[10];

    monthName( buf, sizeof( buf), 9);
    printf( "%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct tm tm = {0};
tm.tm_mon = n - 1;
strftime(s, len, "%B", &tm);
```

Comment: `tm.tm_mon = n-1;` /* range is 0 .. 11 */

Comment: My compiler is showing : "request for member `tm_mon' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: @nth: Which compiler? On which OS?

Comment: @nthrgeek: That's a common error if you have a pointer and used `.` instead of `->`.  (The code in this answer will work.)